# Getting user input through vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of dates in Col K in sheet "Latency". I need the user to input the current date and then the code should find all the dates before the entered date, copy the entire row and paste it in a different sheet named "Previous".

I'm stuck with how to get input from user and integrate it in code and execute the above. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an input box to get the user to input a date, check that what is entered is actually a date, and then run the code you want:

```
Sub test()
Dim userdate

userdate = InputBox("Please enter a date", "Enter Date", Date)
If IsDate(userdate) Then
  'Do stuff here
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get input from the user:

```
Range("A1").Value = InputBox("Give me some input")
```

Read more here:
http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/inputbox-function.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the code below (added some basic error-handling)

```
Sub InputDateBox()

Dim myDateString As String
Dim myDate As Date

myDateString = InputBox("Please enter a date", "Enter Date", Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy"))

If IsDate(myDateString) Then
    myDate = myDateString  
    'Do the rest of your coding here
Else
    MsgBox "Not a valid date format!"
End If

End Sub
```