# Copying rows and pasting in differnt sheet using VBA (code edited)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that gets the date input from the user. What I want to do is:

- To find all the dates before the entered date in COl K of sheet "Latency"
- To copy the entire row and paste it in a different sheet named "Previous".

My code:

```
Sub Previousweek()
Dim userdate

userdate = InputBox("Enter the date", "Enter Date", Date)
 If IsDate(userdate) Then
  'logic here
    End If

End Sub
```

Updated Code:

```
Sub Previousweek()
Dim userdate

userdate = InputBox("Enter the date", "Enter Date", Date)
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("K2:K200")
For Each cell In rng
  If cell.Value < userdate Then
    cell.EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("Previous").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            Sheets("Previous").Paste
        End If
     Next cell
   End Sub
```

This is showing error in below line as Subscript out of range :

```
Sheets("Previous").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying data through date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245780/copying-data-through-date-range)

Comment: Hmmm... Nice use of previously (other question asked 15min ago...) given code. Maybe a bit of your own? This not a free coding site! There are TONS of questions/answers on copy/paste rows on different sheets, you should have enough to get started

Comment: @R3uK LOL, I've just noticed this as well :)

Comment: @ShaiRado : Can't blame him for trying as people still answer (especially on the previous question...), but he updated the question with a bit more of code, so he read my comment!^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change **Previous** in `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Previous")`
to the name of the sheet you want to paste the data in!

```
Sub Previousweek()
    Dim UserDate As String
    Dim CeLL As Range
    UserDate = InputBox("Enter the date", "Enter Date", Date)

    If IsDate(UserDate) Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Previous")
            For Each CeLL In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Latency").Range("K2:K200").Cells
                If CeLL.Value < UserDate Then
                    CeLL.EntireRow.Copy .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            Next CeLL
        End With 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Previous")
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Seriously ? even after your comment ? Just ask him to send us his entire project scope, and we will do it for him (without doing it chunk by chunk every hour ). At least use `DateDiff` :)

Comment: @ShaiRado : Yup, I'm still rushing to the 10k reps! And as said in the other comment, he tried a bit more, which is a good start! Still, I was lazy not to add `DateDiff` indeed but I'd have to convert it to a date too, 2 steps, so long!^^

Comment: here's my aid to help you get to that milestone :)

Comment: @ShaiRado : thx mate! I saw that you passed it recently! ;) Congrats!

Comment: thanks :) I was looking for a check in my email from SO , but there was none :) just a boost to the ego

Comment: You guys have been of tremendous help..I have learned a lot in fact :D...I'm almost close in completing my project :D

Comment: I need to copy the rows from sheet "Latency", but the code does it for the active sheet that is open at run time. I modified a line to this `For Each CeLL In Sheets("Latency").Range("K2:K200").Cells`..But this doesn't work..any idea?

Comment: @ShaiRado : Yup a mail when hitting the 10k milestone would be nice! :)

Comment: @stackmark : Are you pasting in the same workbook? Did it worked before changing the sheet?

Answer (score 1):

find smaller date pseudo code

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("K2:K200")
For Each cell In rng
  if cell.value < userdate then
    //TODO copy to previous
  end if
Next cell
```

Comment: Does this copy the entire row and paste it in different sheet?

Comment: this compares the date this how to copy:  http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=31461.